# Generate and Import CA certificate using Microsoft CA

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

when i want to Request a Certificate  in Active Directory Certificates Services,i have this problem :
[image: error]
[image: error]

Comment: I could almost certainly help you, if you can provide an English translation for your error screens...I'm pretty sure IE will do this for you if you change the language in the browser to English...

Comment: when i want to Request a Certificate in Active Directory Certificates Services,i have this error :